# Angular 6 color-picker with predefined colors

Tags: angular, angular6, color-picker

Is there a color-picker in Angular 6 where I can specify the colors a user can select?
For example I predefine five different colors and the user can then only select a color from this five.

Comment: This post: https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-color-picker shows you how to build your own color picker. I would imagine that you could adjust the resulting code to your needs.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: i solved it with n2g-color-picker: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-color-picker and https://github.com/AndyMeps/ng2-color-picker

Comment: are these ng libs compatible with angular 10+?